# Can With/End With (VB.NET) be used when IDisposable is not available?

Tags: vb.net, using-statement, with-statement

In cases where `Using` can't be used because `IDisposable` is not implemented, is the following code an OK practice for `With`/`End With`? Would this cause a memory leak or would it be better to set an instance variable and then set it to nothing?

```
With New System.IO.FileInfo(sFileName)
   ' Do some work
End With
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The With keyword has *nothing* to do with IDisposable or the Using keyword.  It is just a handy short-cut to avoid having to type the name of the object reference.

```
    With New System.IO.FileInfo(sfilename)
        Console.WriteLine(.Length)    '' note the dot without an object reference
        '' etc..
    End With
```

Which is the same as:

```
    Dim info = New System.IO.FileInfo(sfilename)
    Console.WriteLine(info.Length)
    '' etc..
```

Since FileInfo doesn't implement IDisposable, you otherwise do not have any use for Using.  *Do* avoid assuming that With takes care of disposing the object reference used in the With statement.  It doesn't.  Does kinda make sense that it would but a good 15+ years of it being around stops the VB.NET team from altering its behavior so dramatically.  It was never more than a short-cut to type less code.  Featured pretty heavily in the "Why doesn't C# has the with keyword" questions of yore.  Hot potato in the early days of C# but it hasn't been for a while now.

Comment: In your With/End With sample code, the With statement is instantiating a new System.IO.FileInfo object, when End With is reached there is no object variable to set to nothing. Does the  garbage collector see an unreferenced object and clean it up? In the "same as" example we would have the opportunity to set info = Nothing, but using the With/End With syntax we don't have an object variable to set to nothing.

Comment: There is no point in setting local variables to Nothing, the garbage collector already knows when an object reference no longer matters. It gets that info from the JIT compiler. The code for "info = Nothing" will in fact be removed by the JIT optimizer.  GC.KeepAlive() is relevant here.

Answer (score 2):

`With` has nothing to do with memory or resource usage. It's just a shorthand notation.

Answer (score 0):

```
With
```

is more than just shorthand notation.  If you setting a large number of properties on an object with can slightly improve performance per MSDN, "If the qualification path to the object is long, using With...End With can improve your performance."  (See Remarks on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx ) The reason it does this this is that a with block will only have to get the object reference one time and then it reuses that object reference for each subsequent call.  If you explicitly list the object each time the runtime has to get the object reference multiple times.   It's not a big difference but it can be important in some cases.

Comment: "With" is a shorthand notation, though what exactly it's shorthand notation *for* varies with the nature of its argument.  If the argument is a value type referenced from an array, and a closure within the With makes use of that reference, "With Foo(index) ... .X=5" is roughly equivalent to "$TEMP1=Foo : $TEMP2=index : ... $TEMP1($TEMP2)=5".